# Contradiction in value of $\psi (1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fake-proofs

What is the value of $\psi (1)$ ? If we take the definition in terms of derivative of Gamma function, we get $\psi (1) = \dfrac{\Gamma'(1)}{\Gamma(1)} = -\gamma$. But, if we consider the series representation i.e, $\psi (a) = - \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n+a}$, then $\psi(1) = - \zeta(1)$ which diverges.

Here, $\psi (x)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

Why are there contradictory answers?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misread the series representation. It should be \begin{align}
\psi(n)&=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k\\
&=H_{n-1}-\gamma
\end{align}
where $H_n$ denotes the $n$th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). Note that this is only defined for natural numbers $n$ (where the sum from $1$ to $0$ is the so-called "empty sum", which is equal to $0$. Also note that $H_0=0$). So actually you've misread two things, since also $\psi(1)\neq\gamma$, but $\psi(1)=-\gamma$.

Comment: But according to wikipedia, the series representation is true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Regularization

Comment: I'm not sure what they mean by "regularization of divergent integrals", so I unfortunately cannot answer that question. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @FlamingNinja: You misread what Wikipedia says. That article speaks about attributing finite values to **divergent series** $($ which is what **regularization** means $),$ and $\psi(a)$ is s very logical choice, in [certain contexts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627069), for the sum in question.

Comment: @Lucian Oh ok. Thanks!